# Saving user settings in Metro app using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, settings

How to saving user settings in Metro app using VB.NET? I want to save the password at first time open the metro apps.And open the metro apps need password to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx) for an overview of all your storage options.

More specifically though, if you do need to store secure information on the client device (always a risk there) then use the [PasswordVault APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx)

The [Credential Locker example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PasswordVault-f01be74a) should help.